# How to fix the faulty mailform output since TYPO3 6.2.47 ELTS?

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

Since the last update to TYPO3 6.2.47 ELTS forms (the old core forms; without use of sysext "form") are no longer rendered normally ...

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="mailformname" size="30" value="" />
```

... but the input fields seem to be sent through an HTML encoder. It now looks like this in the source code:

```
&lt;input type=&quot;text&quot; name=&quot;name&quot; id=&quot;mailformname&quot; size=&quot;30&quot; value=&quot;&quot; /&gt;
```

How can this be fixed?

I couldn't find anything related to this in the changelog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a new parseFunc, which is responsible for the issue

```
tt_content.mailform.20.stdWrap.parseFunc =< lib.parseFunc
```

You can overwrite this as follows

```
tt_content.mailform.20.stdWrap.parseFunc >
```